# Is there a way with rufus-scheduler to schedule a job every 5 minutes, starting at the completion of the last job run?

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

So if I have a job that is scheduled to run every 5 minutes, and one time while running it happens to take 4 minutes, I'd like it to still wait 5 minutes til it starts the next time, rather than waiting only 1 minute.  Any way to do that with rufus-scheduler?

It doesn't look like this is supported directly, although I could perhaps schedule the job itself at the end of its run.  The only issue I have with that is a bootstrapping one. (so if the answer to part 1 is no, then is there a built-in way with rufus-scheduler to handle the bootstrapping case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rufus-scheduler supports "interval" jobs.

They are described in the README:
https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/#in-at-every-interval-cron

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

s = Rufus::Scheduler.new

s.interval('5m') do |job|
  puts "Doing it..."
  sleep(rand * 1000)
  puts "done. See you in #{job.interval}."
end

#s.join
```

If that's not what you were looking, please do note that, in the case of an "every" job, it's OK to modify the "next_time" in flight, like in:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

s = Rufus::Scheduler.new

s.every '5m' do |job|
  t = Time.now
  puts "doing the job..."
  # ...
  if Time.now - t > 4 * 60
    job.next_time = Time.now + 1 * 60
  end
  puts "next_time will be #{job.next_time}."
end

#s.join
```

That could come in handy as well.

https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#every-jobs-and-changing-the-next_time-in-flight

Comment: Thanks -- interval jobs are what I was looking for -- I somehow ended up reading the rubyforge documentation, which doesn't mention the interval jobs (and appears significantly outdated) instead of the github README.md -- thanks for finding that for me.

Comment: I'll have to override that old doc. Thanks for pointing at that problem.